# Can't Store and Retrieve From Chrome Storage

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-app

First of all, I apologize if this question sounds similar to others. I've done a lot of research and I guess I can't piece together my situation and issues other people have with this API.

I am creating an chrome app that basically demonstrates the ability to store and retrieve data from the Chrome Storage API. Once I'm comfortable doing this, I can implement this in a larger application I'm making.

However, I can't seem to get the basic app working. Here's the relevant code:

"storage.js"

```
function Store(key,data) {

    console.log("Data: " + data);

    chrome.storage.local.set({ key: data }, function () {

        console.log("Secret Message Saved!");

    });

}

function Retrieve() {

    chrome.storage.local.get(function (data) {

        console.log("The data stored is:" + data);

    });

}
```

"master.js" (main script)

```
var myKey = "secretMessage";
var myData = "Pssst!";

Store(myKey, myData);

Retrieve(myKey);

console.log("Done!");
```

I'm at a loss. The output I get is:

```
Data: Pssst!
Done!
Secret Message Saved!
The data stored is:[object Object]
```

It appears that either I'm storing wrong or retrieving wrong.

I've looked through the documentation. Maybe I'm just not understanding the concept of the API and what it is able to store and retrieve. I'm fairly new to coding in the javascript language. Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Somewhat curious: why are you using a chrome storage instead of universal localStorage/indexdb so that your code will work on all web platforms that support modern APIs instead of intentionally baking platform-incompatibility in?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans As this is my first time writing a chrome app, and because I'm very new to the field, I'm not actually familiar with that means of storage. How complicated is it to pick up versus chrome storage api?

Comment: not very, you can see the localstorage api documentation here: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Comment: it's a global object that you just have access to, and can store string:string pairs (and, thus, because of JSON.stringify and JSON.parse, pretty much arbitrary data). I guess my real question was "why do you need a chrome app, instead of just writing a universal web app instead" =)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans The reason I am using a chrome app is because I need to be able to modify browser content as part of the larger application I am writing.

Comment: especially then it's worth looking at staying cross platform compatible. Firefox now supports [web extensions](http://arewewebextensionsyet.com/) just like Chrome, so write it smart, and run it on multiple platforms. Saying that, though, looks like chrome.local *is* part of the webextension API =)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans With that said, do you recommend sticking with chrome.storage? Or do you recommend using the aforementioned localStorage/indexdb?

Comment: still worth looking into - if localStorage/index can do what you need, given its much wider support right now, it's still worth using instead of low support chrome.local

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First,
`chrome.storage.local.set` & `chrome.storage.local.get`
are asynchronous methods, you have to wait till `chrome.storage.local.set` stores data in storage, then you should call `chrome.storage.local.get`.

Second,
`chrome.storage.local.get` is returning an object. You can view object by using `.toString()` or `JSON.stringify(data)`

```
function Store(key,data, callback) {

    console.log("Data: " + data);

    chrome.storage.local.set({ key: data }, function () {

        console.log("Secret Message Saved!");
        callback(true);

    });

}

function Retrieve(success) {

    chrome.storage.local.get(function (data) {

        console.log("The data stored is:" + JSON.stringify(data));

    });
}

var myKey = "secretMessage";
var myData = "Pssst!";

Store(myKey, myData, Retrieve);

console.log("Done!");
```

Answer (score 1):

I've used this callback method without a problem.

```
function loadSelectedStyle(){
    chrome.storage.local.get('defaultColorSet', function (result) {
        console.log(result.defaultColorSet);
        defaultColors(result.defaultColorSet);
    });
}
```

If you just write 'result' to the console log, you can see the entire object, by adding the key to result you get the data.